# Inner Join Nested Inside Update Statement SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, inner-join

I am trying to write a query that performs an inner join within an update statement.

Here is the current query I am working with:

```
UPDATE 
    singulation1.`q096_cq33r08-ds01-n-testtable`
SET 
    visual = t2.visual,
    inspection_status = t2.inspection_status,
    inspector_name = t2.inspector_name
FROM 
    singulation1.`q096_cq33r08-ds01-n-testtable` t1
INNER JOIN 
    singulation1.`q014_bq31t05-dw30-x` t2
ON 
    (t1.print = t2.print AND t1.id3 = t2.id3);
```

Something about MySql does not like the FROM clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For updates, you specify the join in the update clause

```
UPDATE
    singulation1.`q096_cq33r08-ds01-n-testtable` AS t1
    INNER JOIN singulation1.`q014_bq31t05-dw30-x` AS t2
      ON t1.print = t2.print AND t1.id3 = t2.id3
SET
    t1.visual = t2.visual
    t1.inspection_status = t2.inspection_status,
    t1.inspector_name = t2.inspector_name
```

Comment: I don't get any errors anymore, but the results show that 0 rows where effected.  This tells me that something is incorrect because there is a 1:1 mapping between the tables on the id3 and print columns.

Comment: Is either `print` or `id3` NULL?

Comment: @kformeck What do you get if you perform `SELECT * FROM [the table/join definition from above]`